# Print multiple worksheets at once based off user selection

Tags: vba, excel

I need a way to be able to print multiple worksheets as one job, based off of what worksheets the user wants to print.

I have a worksheet where in column A I have a lists of all the worksheets in the workbook.  Column B has a `dropdown` list where the user will either select Y or N to indicate if they want to print that sheet.

What my code is supposed to do is print all of the worksheets that have a Y in column B as one job. I have a cell reference called `FirstSheetPrint` that copies the name of the first worksheet in the list of worksheets that has a Y in column B.  I then take that name and add "'s around it so that it can be uses as a worksheet name later.  Then I loop through all the rows that have a Y and add "'s and the worksheet name to a single string (the string keeps growing as the loop continues).

My problem is that in the end when I try to assign this string of Sheet names to an array I get an error Subscript out of range.  I have added a screen shot of my message box that shows what the final string looks like and a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub PrintAllSheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim DoesPrint As Boolean
Dim SheetsToPrint As String
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim StartCount As Integer
Dim StartRange As String
Dim totalString As String

DoesPrint = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

If DoesPrint = False Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Else
End If

SheetsToPrint = Sheets("Printing").Range("FirstSheetPrint").Value
SheetCount = Sheets("Printing").Range("SheetsToPrintCount").Value
StartCount = 4

If SheetsToPrint = "N" Then
    MsgBox "Please select which sheets you would like to print"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    SheetsToPrint = ("""" & SheetsToPrint & """")
    For i = 1 To SheetCount

        If Sheets("Printing").Range("N" & StartCount).Value > 0 Then
            SheetsToPrint = (SheetsToPrint & ", " & """" & Sheets("Printing").Range("L" & StartCount).Value & """")
            StartCount = StartCount + 1
        Else
            StartCount = StartCount + 1
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox ("We will print: " & SheetsToPrint)
End If

Sheets(Array(SheetsToPrint)).PrintOut


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brS3x.png)
[Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1wvM.png)

Comment: Check if your sheet name or range name is correct

Comment: Yeah the sheet names are correct.  I used copy/paste to make sure everything was 100% accurate.  I am assuming the problem is with the actual syntax on the `Sheets(Array(SheetsToPrint)).Printout` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, code is untested.

```
Sub PrintAllSheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim DoesPrint       As Boolean
Dim SheetsToPrint   As String
Dim SheetCount      As Integer
Dim StartCount      As Integer
Dim MyArr()         As String
Dim StartRange      As String
Dim totalString     As String
Dim i               As Long

DoesPrint = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

If DoesPrint = False Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If

SheetsToPrint = Sheets("Printing").Range("FirstSheetPrint").Value
SheetCount = Sheets("Printing").Range("SheetsToPrintCount").Value
StartCount = 4

If SheetsToPrint = "N" Then
    MsgBox "Please select which sheets you would like to print"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    'SheetsToPrint = ("""" & SheetsToPrint & """") 'Not sure if this is needed
    For i = 1 To SheetCount
        If Sheets("Printing").Range("N" & StartCount).Value > 0 Then
            SheetsToPrint = (SheetsToPrint & "," & Sheets("Printing").Range("L" & StartCount).Value)
            StartCount = StartCount + 1
        Else
            StartCount = StartCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("We will print: " & SheetsToPrint)
End If

'Split the string into an array
MyArr = Split(SheetsToPrint, ",")

'Print the array
Sheets(MyArr).PrintOut

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This just prints out all of the sheets individually.  I need it to all print out as one job, because we print to pdf so if I use this method then every worksheet is a separate file.

Comment: See my comment: 'This should also work as a 1 liner, I think
'Sheets(MyArr).PrintOut

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that after I ran it.  It works, but for some reason still splits it into 3 jobs.  I have 16 worksheets that I print.  It prints the first 10 then 4 then 2.  But it works!  Thank you so much!